# Trying to get property of non-object in view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a link ending with index.php/welcome/item/1

I have my controller welcome.php with the function item

```
public function item($id)
{
    $data   = array();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $data['title'] = "item";
    $this->load->view('header', $data);
    $data['item']=$this->port_model->get_item($id);
    $this->load->view('item',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

and my model with the get_item function

```
public function get_item($id)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('portfolio');
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $item = $query->result();
    }
```

In my item view i want to echo info out of the database. Why doesn't it do that now

```
<h1>item</h1>
<?php echo $item->naam; ?>
```

Error i get on the page:
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/item.php

Line Number: 2

The page gets loaded normal, no problems.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I see too many questions like this. Take the time to learn how to [interpret errors and fix your code](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/05/fixing-php-errors/).

Comment: try to do  return $this->item = $query->result();

Comment: Said another way, `$item` is not an object. You need to back-trace to figure out why.

Comment: Okay nevermind my answer. Didn't expect this to be specific to Codeigniter. I'll delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're expecting one single result, your get_item function should

```
return $query->row();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace in your `get_item` function this :

> **result()**
>
> This function returns the query result as an array of objects, or an
>   empty array on failure.

```
return $item = $query->result();
```

Like this :

> **row()**
>
> This function returns a single result row. If your query has more than
>   one row, it returns only the first row. The result is returned as an
>   object.

```
return $item = $query->row();
```

[Documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the library database ( `$this->load->database();` ) and the model (`$this->load->model('port_model');`) :

Result:

```
<code>public function item($id)
{
    $data   = array();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $data['title'] = "item";
    $this->load->view('header', $data);
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('port_model');
    $data['item']=$this->port_model->get_item($id);
    $this->load->view('item',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}</code>
```